# How to run youtube in ios6 App

Tags: json, video, youtube, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have problems to run a video directly after a click on a cell in a tableView. I use youtube API, didSelectRowAtIndexPath to launch video. And I have differents possibilities to have the video with their JSON result:

```
 "player": {
 "default": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHQCvSbHW-k&feature=youtube_gdata_player",
 "mobile": "https://m.youtube.com/details?v=EHQCvSbHW-k"
},
"content": {
 "5": "https://www.youtube.com/v/EHQCvSbHW-k?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata",
 "1": "rtsp://v3.cache1.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwnpW8cmvQJ0EBMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp",
 "6": "rtsp://v5.cache4.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwnpW8cmvQJ0EBMYESARFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"
},
```

I try with directs links (mobile & default) but it was not worked with MPMoviePlayerController.
I try with UIApplication but the video is redirected to Safari.
I try with the two .gp3 links above and this tuto (it works great with their .mov video) : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_6_iPhone_Application 
. But it don't want to work with .gp3 ...

My code is :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"rtsp://v3.cache1.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwnpW8cmvQJ0EBMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp"];

moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

So my questions are :

- Can I play youtube video directly with the .gp3 link ?
- Or, its better with the original link ?
- Can I run rtsp in ios App ? 
  And how to do ? Many thanks

(my json https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/ZapSpi0nDOTcom/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&prettyprint=true )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't play rtsp on the iPhone without resorting to a 3rd party player (which incidentally works pretty well) so your only choice is use the youtube api and play HLS, which would be the https links. The youtube api comes with samples. I think you need to use a webview or some kind of wrapper.

I know of one there are probably others

https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView